# android strings.xml japnese shows only a series of blocks in tags

Tags: android, eclipse

In one of my project in eclipse the strings.xml is no longer showing the japanese strings in the xml file, 
Its only showing a series of vertical rectangles,

my other strings.xml such as german, spanish , french etc are showing fine ..

Any idea what may have gone wrong ? seems like the text editor is not interpretting the encoding right ?

When I copy the string from there to here for example in the stackoverflow editor, it shows the strings fine..

```
 <string name="dialog_message">"発信者名"</string>
```

But does not show in eclipse's xml editor.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the Eclipse editor is using a font that isn't capable of displaying Japanese characters. Which font is your Eclipse editor set to use? Ensure that it is using a Unicode-capable font.

Comment: That would explain it, then. Some versions of Consolas don't support the entire Unicode set. What happens when you switch the font to use, say, Lucida Sans Unicode?

Comment: Can you put the file on Dropbox or something and publish a link here?

Comment: Here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/7epl8gtmymm89dw/strings.xml but dropbox seems to show it fine, ..

Comment: I can see that. That means that the file is encoded correctly. It also shows fine on my Eclipse installation, as well as Notepad++. The file is OK; it's a view-related problem. Right-click the file in Eclipse, choose Properties, then select the "Resource" item from the left pane and look at "Text file encoding" on the right. What do you see?

Comment: says: default determined from content-type : UTF-8 , I explicitely changed to UTF8 to but did not work

Comment: Then it definitely means that the font used by the editor isn't capable of displaying Japanese characters. I suggest you try loading this file into a brand new Eclipse workspace and see what happens. Somewhere in your Eclipse configuration, there's a setting that causes this particular editor to use a Unicode-incapable font.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, menu `Edit` and `Set Encoding`.

There you should find an encoding format that suites your requirements.

Regards